# No me muestra la imagen en mi formulario

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

Estoy creando un formulario en Angular y cuando voy a importar la imagen de la card del formulario no me muestra la imagen, sale el símbolo de la imagen rota... aquí tenéis el código de el div con la img:

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-lg-5 d-none d-md-block">
  <img src="../../assets/chicaCepillo.jpg"
   alt="login form" class="img-fluid" style="border-radius: 1rem 0 0 1rem;" />
</div>
```

Me muestra el siguiente error la consola:

GET http://localhost:4200/assets/chicaCepillo.jpg 404 (Not Found)

Gracias por los aportes que me podáis dar, saludos.

Comment: El código está bien, pero tal y como indica el mensaje de error, el servidor no encuentra la imagen en dicha ruta. Comprueba que la imagen se encuentra ahí.

Comment: Tienes razón, como siempre fallos de novato y por no fijarme, he encontrado por fin la solución al error, básicamente había creado otra carpeta assets pensando que no estaba y le había metido dentro las imágenes... lo que he hecho básicamente es eliminar dicha carpeta y crear una carpeta  llamada "media" dentro de la carpeta assets que crea Angular de manera predeterminada y dentro meter las imágenes y por fin las ha mostrado correctamente... ¡Gracias igualemente por tu comentario!

Answer (score 0):

Como siempre fallos de novato y por no fijarme, he encontrado por fin la solución al error, básicamente había creado otra carpeta assets pensando que no estaba y le había metido dentro las imágenes... lo que he hecho básicamente es eliminar dicha carpeta y crear una carpeta llamada "media" dentro de la carpeta assets que crea Angular de manera predeterminada y dentro meter las imágenes y por fin las ha mostrado correctamente... ¡Gracias igualemente por tu comentario!